# jboss run.bat file is not running through java program

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, jboss

When I double click on run.bat file present at C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin location, then I jboss is starting perfectly. Even through cmd also it is starting perfectly.
But when I am trying to run this bat file through a java program it is not starting. it is showing like "Unable to read the logging configuration from 'file:logging.properties' (java.io.FileNotFoundException: logging.properties (The system cannot find the file specified))"

After that I modified the bat file as below
I changed a line from(In below change I have changed %DIRNAME% to ”C:\Java\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\logging.properties)

```
rem Setup JBoss specific properties
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=%PROGNAME% -Dlogging.configuration=file:%DIRNAME%logging.properties %JAVA_OPTS%"
```

to

```
rem Setup JBoss specific properties
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=%PROGNAME% -Dlogging.configuration=file:”C:\Java\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\logging.properties\logging.properties"%JAVA_OPTS%"
```

Now it running but cmd is hanging(text are blinking) and server is not starting.

And the java prog I ve written in eclipse is as below:

```
public class Batch {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {       
        String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", "C:\\jboss-6.1.0.Final\\bin\\run.bat"};
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec(command);
        p.waitFor();

    }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
  }

}
```

any body have any idea how to resolve it? Any help would be highly appriciated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on windows, wrap `C:\Java\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\logging.properties` into `""` (double qoute).

```
rem Setup JBoss specific properties
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=%PROGNAME% -Dlogging.configuration=file:"C:\Java\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\logging.properties" "%JAVA_OPTS%"
```

Comment: hey Thanks for the reply but Problem still persist :-(

Comment: @santosh sorry, I just change my answer please try again. your path C:\Java\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\logging.properties\logging.properties should be change to C:\Java\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\logging.properties. However, you should make sure about file logging.properties is contain inside folder C:\Java\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin

Answer (score 0):

I tried to tweak this by writing a batch helper file.This contains steps to navigate to run.bat folder and execute the run.bat file. The runHelper.bat file looks like this.

```
    cd\
    cd C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\
    run.bat >LoggerOutput.txt
    exit
```

And my java code looks like this.

```
    String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", "C:\\jboss-6.1.0.Final\\bin\\runHelper.bat"};
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = r.exec(command);
    p.waitFor();
```